# Git - how to resolve conflicts from each commit in one step during rebase without squashing?

Tags: git

```
  A---B---C topic
 /
D---G master
```

Say I have the above branch structure in git. If I do `git checkout topic` followed by `git rebase master`, from what I've experienced, I will have to resolve conflicts for commits A, B, and C one at a time. I'm looking for a way to avoid having to resolve conflicts for each commit one at a time. Squashing the commits during rebase seems like an option, but is it possible to keep the commits separate and only have to perform conflict resolution for the most recent "topic" commit? Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to rebase "topic" onto "master" and only have to resolve conflicts between "C" and "G" without squashing all commits into one. Maybe there's something I've misunderstood, but it seems to me that since "C" is the most recent commit and the one I'm interested in, why do I have to resolve conflicts for "A" and "B" first? I'm specifically interested in doing this for `git pull --rebase` as well.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Turn on [`git rerere`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html).  See also http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: how to resolve all conflicts at once?

A:  you can't because during a rebase, the rebasing tools has no way to foresee what's coming. Rebase really is a scripted chained cherry-pick. You could try to first merge the changes on a disposable branch with rerere enabled but 1) it will require more steps than just solving each conflicts and 2) there is no garantee that you will not have to resolve conflicts anyway.

Q2: Maybe there's something I've misunderstood, but it seems to me that since "C" is the most recent commit and the one I'm interested in, why do I have to resolve conflicts for "A" and "B" first?

A: Yes there is. While you are rebasing, you will not have updated master anyway, you will only apply the changes on a newer master version. So maybe you will want to drop C or B or even A. The thing with git that I think is revolutionary is that you have to stop thinking in terms of "most up to date code" but rather in terms on staging changes (in terms of rolling out and/or moving new dev/features into production/deployment/delivery). I'd be tempted to quote Doc Brown to McFly if I could do it exactly.

So yes it might mean that the best solution is to squash all the commits as one. The line of though behind git rebase is that the norm should be no conflicts and conflicts should be forseeable. Not a surprise. Because conflicts is synonymous which CHANGE and change should be a new [version](http://semver.org/). If the conflicts are coming up when you add new stuff, refactor or plain bug fix, it is more a symptom of poor architecture than poor git kungfu/features. YMMV.

Comment: That was pretty helpful, especially the comment about "most up to date code". The main reason I asked was that sometimes it would have been several local commits since I last pulled from the remote master branch - I would then do `git pull --rebase` (which is what I've been encouraged to do) and have to resolve conflicts for past commits whose code had since been overwritten and was no longer wanted, one at a time. I'm pretty sure I haven't been using the smartest workflow though, and I'm going to try to not do so many frivolous local commits.

Comment: There is many trick to work around that. The done than undone commits from upstream are bad practice but something you will most inevitably have to face. My favorite trick to resolve those is to basically 1) keep a safec copy of my original changes 2) rebase gradually on upstream commits (rather than on origin/master). Each successful partial rebase is a victory. 3) you could git checkout origin/master -b test and git rebase -i master and squash the upstream commits. Rebasing on the squashed upstream should be easy. That version should be easier to rebase on origin/master. Not sure if clear.